# Sort and Print Average Values from Column (Array) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am able to generate average from 2D Array (columns). Though I am unable to figure out, how to sort that average. I do have to create a new array (`rankedscore[]`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
int rankedArtist() // ranked artist based on score
{
    const int A1_SIZE = 5,  A2_ROWSIZE =5, A2_COLSIZE =10;
    string Artist[A1_SIZE]={ "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };
    int Scores[A2_ROWSIZE][A2_COLSIZE] = {{5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10},{8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
    {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},{5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{5,6,8,10,4,0,0,0,0,0}};

    cout << "\n\n\t-------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tRanking by Artist"<< endl;
    cout << "\t===========================================" << endl;

    int total = 0;
    float faverage;
    double AverageScore[5];
    double average;
    double rankedscore[A2_ROWSIZE];


    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        cout << "\n\t" << Artist[x] << "\t\t";

        for (int col = 0; col < A2_COLSIZE; col++)
        {
            total+=Scores[x][col];
        }
        faverage = (float)total / 10.0f;

        average = total = 0;
        AverageScore[x] = faverage;
    }
}
```

Comment: "how to sort that average" You want to sort the artists based on their average?

Comment: yes DyP.. and i am trying different things, not making sense to me.

Comment: *Remarks:* You're missing a `return` statement. There's `faverage` and `average`, though the latter one is never read from (and there's a conversion to float then to double because of `faverage`). There are some redundant constants, like `A1_SIZE`, `A2_ROWSIZE`, and the `5` in `AverageScore[5]` and in `x<5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Though I am unable to figure out, how to sort that average.

I would use a `std::pair` to map the artist to the score. Then I would use `std::sort` to implement the sorting:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> artists{ "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> scores{{ 3, 2, 1 }, { 5, 4, 3 }};

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> chart;

    for (auto name = artists.begin(); name != artists.end(); ++name)
    {
        for (auto score = scores.begin(); score != scores.end(); ++score)
        {
            int total = std::accumulate(score->begin(), score->end(), 0);
            int average = total  / score->size();
            chart.push_back(std::make_pair(*name, average));
        }
    }

    struct
    {
        bool operator()(std::pair<std::string, int> p1, std::pair<std::string, int> p2) const
        {
            return p1.second < p2.second;
        }
    } Predicate;

    std::sort(chart.begin(), chart.end(), Predicate);

    for (auto it = chart.begin(); it != chart.end(); ++it)
    {
         std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: l'm still trying to edit the code so it may not work right now. :(

Comment: yeh i am getting an error :
in c++98 artists must be intialized by a constructor not by '{...}'

Comment: @mani Try compiling your program with the command line argument `-std=c++11`. Are you still getting the same error afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::sort` to sort the rankedscore array. Afterwards, just make a for loop and print its values.

You can view an example of how to use `std::sort` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

**EDIT:** As RankedScore and Artists should be related, you could use a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) structure. Use the average scores as keys. Then you can sort the map by its keys and print the key values (the artists) in order.

Comment: The problem is that `AverageScore` and `Artists` are independent data structures, but their data is dependent (an artist's name has the same *index* as the artist's score).

Comment: DyP I dont know how to combine them, so then when sort is done, scores are their for corresponding artist.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, thanks.

A map structure could be used, instead. So he can get AverageScore and Artists related.

Comment: guys what would be the fix to this, in easiet language possible for a newbie like me :). thanks.